# Format of a VBP File reference line

Tags: reference, vb6

Can any one tell me the format of the reference=\ lines in a Visual Basic 6 (VB6) project vbp file? Particularly what look like version numbers but I don't think are in the middle?
e.g.

```
Reference=*\G{835341D8-AF69-4753-BD84-89B39E426EBC}#1.0#0#C:\CASimpleCom.dll#CASimpleCom
```

I think the first part is the COM GUID, the last two parts are the location of the DLL and it's internal name but what are the numbers, i.e. #1.0#0#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UUID is the typelib ID, the 1.0 is the typelib version number.

The third part, a "0" here, is the LCID.  This is commonly 0 (unless a localized build of the library has been referenced).

After that comes the file that contains the type information, and last comes descriptive text (the typelib's HelpString value).

Comment: what do you mean by typelibe version number? is that held somewhere in the referenced COM object equivelent vbp file?

Comment: Depending on the compiler and linker and the options chosen, the type library can be a separate .TLB file or a resource embedded within a .DLL, .OCX, .EXE library (an ActiveX EXE is a library).  The interfaces defined in the TLB are versioned using the typelib's version number.  You will probably need to research *binary compatibility* and you might start with http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161137